# Database schema concerning multiple front-end forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, database-design

I have little experience when it comes to good practice for managing database schema so I'm looking for a little help.

I am trying to organize tables in the most scalable and efficient way. On the front-end are forms which all overlap fields but only slightly. If I used one table in which all forms are submitted, I'd have many null entries. On the other hand, I could have each form correspond to a respective table.

However, I'm imagining in the future, when having to collect data from possibly dozens of different tables, using this sort of schema may get out of hand.

If anyone had any guidance on how to organize this data, so that as the amount of data grows, accessing it is still manageable.

Comment: I think you don't have to design your databa-schema looking the form of the forms. I think you could think about how the data is structured in your business logic. 

For example: you could have a User table with some fields to fill out in a form but internally you could have others fields for your interests or your signup form could have fields for fill in differents tables of your database.

Comment: There are many duplicate questions re one table with nulls vs many tables, and likely too re whether DB design should reflect input forms. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not very important, e.g. if we are not talking about 1000s requests per second, you may try traditional pseudo-OOP way, e.g. define super-entities that will have common fields, and sub-entities that will have specific fields, and relate as 1:1 to super-entity. The alternative is so-called `tall table`, or `EAV`, where each row represent one field in the form. This way, you don't have to change schema when new form is added or existing one is modified, but you will give up some capabilities of the traditional design.